# How to separate logic in the service layer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

As I know there are controller, service and repository layers

I have a method that

1. creates a new order if no order was created before
2. updates existing order if there is already existing order

My current code in `OrderService` in the service layer:

```
public void addOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
    sum=0;
    User user = em.find(User.class, 1L);    
    List<Order> existingPendingOrder = orderRepository.findAllByUserIdAndStatus(1L,EOrderStatus.PENDING);
    List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    if(existingPendingOrder.size()==1) {
        // ===================================================================
        //  IF USER ALREADY HAS A PENDING ORDER THEN JUST UPDATE EXISTING ORDER
        // ====================================================================
        Order existingOrder = existingPendingOrder.get(0);
        
        orderRequest.getOrderItems().stream().forEach(e-> {
            sum+= e.getTotal();
            Product product = em.find(Product.class, e.getProductId());
            OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(
                    e.getQuantity(),
                    e.getPrice(),
                    new Date(),
                    product);    
    orderItem.setOrder(existingOrder);
        orderItems.add(orderItem);
    });
        existingOrder.setFinalTotal(sum);
        existingOrder.getOrderItems().clear();
        existingOrder.getOrderItems().addAll(orderItems);
        orderRepository.save(existingOrder);    
        
        
        
    }else {
        // ===================================================================
        //IF USER DOES NOT HAVE EXISTING ORDER, THEN CREATE NEW
        // ====================================================================
        
        Order newOrder = new Order();
        newOrder.setUser(user);
        newOrder.setStatus(EOrderStatus.PENDING);
        newOrder.setOrderItems(orderItems);
        newOrder.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        orderRequest.getOrderItems().stream().forEach(e-> {
            sum+= e.getTotal();
            Product product = em.find(Product.class, e.getProductId());
            OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(
                    e.getQuantity(),
                    e.getPrice(),
                    new Date(),
                    product);
            orderItem.setOrder(newOrder);
            orderItems.add(orderItem);
        });
        newOrder.setFinalTotal(sum);
        orderRepository.save(newOrder);
    }
     
}
```

#### What I want to do

I want to separate the logic to be something like below, but where is the best place to store the logic above? Is that called DTO?

```
public void addOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {

    User user = em.find(User.class, 1L);    
    List<Order> existingPendingOrder =orderRepository.findAllByUserIdAndStatus(1L,EOrderStatus.PENDING);


    if(existingPendingOrder.size()==1) {
        // ===================================================================
        //  IF USER ALREADY HAS A PENDING ORDER THEN JUST UPDATE EXISTING ORDER
        // ====================================================================
         updateOrder()

    }else {
        // ===================================================================
        //IF USER DOES NOT HAVE EXISTING ORDER, THEN CREATE NEW
        // ====================================================================
        
         createOrder()
    }
     
}
```

Comment: The logic will remain in service layer only. Data transfer object (DTO), formerly known as value objects or VO, is a design pattern used to transfer data between software application subsystems. DTOs are often used in conjunction with data access objects to retrieve data from a database

Comment: Update case feels little weird here, how the client is interacting to your service layer through REST like API?